# Como inverter a posição de uma div(e seu conteudo e atributos) com outra div?

Tags: jquery, div

Desejo fazer isso com jQuery, qual a forma mais elegante de se fazer isso?

Supondo o cenário a seguir, como ficaria se eu quisesse trocar de posição a div2 com a div3? (não postarei o meu código real que é muito grande)

```html
<body>
    <div id="div1" class="parte1" style="color:black">
        <p> Conteúdo da Div </p>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class="parte2" style="color:blue">
        <p> Conteúdo da Div </p>
    </div>
    <div id="div3" class="parte3" style="color:red">
        <p> Conteúdo da Div </p>
    </div>
    <div id="div4" class="parte4" style="color:green">
        <p> Conteúdo da Div </p>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Quem chegou agora, ignore os *downvotes* e dê uma olhada na minha [resposta](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/669/como-inverter-a-posicao-de-uma-dive-seu-conteudo-e-atributos-com-outra-div/675#675) para ver um método que troca elementos independentemente da estrutura.

Comment: Não acredito que ninguém ainda sugeriu a [solução clássica...](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/669/como-inverter-a-posicao-de-uma-dive-seu-conteudo-e-atributos-com-outra-div/690#690)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Método simplificado:

Uma forma de relizar a operação pretendida, com pouco código mas limitado a elementos que se encontram um ao lado do outro, é fazer uso do método de jQuery [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/), onde o que é feito é pegar no `$ele2` e passar o mesmo para antes do `$ele1`:

```js
function switchElements($ele1, $ele2) {
    $ele1.before($ele2);
}

switchElements($('#div2'), $('#div3'));
```

<sup>Ver exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xWA54/).</sup>

Também podemos utilizar o método de jQuery [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) que fará o inverso:

```js
function switchElements($ele1, $ele2) {
    $ele2.after($ele1);
}

switchElements($('#div2'), $('#div3'));
```

<sup>Ver exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29gtg/).</sup>

**Nota:**
Isto são tudo métodos de jQuery muito semelhantes aos já sugeridos em outras respostas.
Por outro lado é limitado pelo facto de que a sensação de "trocar de posição" só é tida se os elementos estiverem lado a lado.

---

## Método genérico:

Uma maneira para realizar o pretendido pode ser atingida fazendo uso do método de jQuery [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) e do método [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

```js
// cache elements
var $div1 = $('#div1'),
    $div2 = $('#div2');

// clone elements and their contents
var $div1Clone = $div1.clone(),
    $div2Clone = $div2.clone();

// switch places
$div1.replaceWith($div2Clone);
$div2.replaceWith($div1Clone);
```

<sup>Ver exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vsXS9/).</sup>

---

Passando este exemplo para uma função:

```js
function switchElements($ele1, $ele2) {

    // clone elements and their contents
    var $ele1Clone = $ele1.clone(),
        $ele2Clone = $ele2.clone();

    // switch places
    $ele1.replaceWith($ele2Clone);
    $ele2.replaceWith($ele1Clone);
}
```

Utilização:

```js
// cache elements
var $ele1 = $('#div2'),
    $ele2 = $('#div3');

switchElements($ele1, $ele2);
```

<sup>Ver exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34sxj/).</sup>

Comment: O "simplificado" não funciona. Experimente inverter a `#div2` com a `#div4`.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Não, não funciona dessa forma, por isso tive o cuidado de deixar a nota que esse método só faz "troca" quando os elementos estão lado a lado. Por isso é que não sugeri em primeiro lugar. Para trocar elementos "longe" uns dos outros, é preciso utilizar o "método genérico". :) ver [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34Jcy/).

Answer (score 4):

Vejo muitas abordagens diferentes, mas nenhuma usando o clássico algoritmo de se trocar duas variáveis de valor:

```
swap = a
a = b
b = swap
```

No caso de jQuery ficaria assim:

```
function trocar(a, b) {
    var swap = $("<span/>");
    a.after(swap).detach();
    b.after(a).detach();
    swap.after(b).detach();
}
```

Esclarecendo:

1. `a.after(swap)` coloca `swap` logo após `a`, retornando a si mesma;
2. `a.detach()` remove a si mesma do DOM - mas [mantendo dados e ouvintes](http://api.jquery.com/detach/):

   > O método `.detach()` é o mesmo que `.remove()`, exceto que `.detach()` mantém todos os dados jQuery associados com os elementos removidos. Esse método é útil quando os elementos removidos serão reinseridos no DOM em um momento posterior.

[Exemplo completo](http://jsfiddle.net/LXfyr/1/) no jsFiddle.

Answer (score 3):

## Nota

Minha resposta inicial era simplista e não funcionava em 100% dos casos. Fiz então uma implementação um tanto complexa, mas ainda não fiquei satisfeito, assim como com as outras respostas.

Estou considerando apenas as soluções gerais, isto é, que se aplicam a troca de quaisquer elementos em níveis e posições diferentes.

## Análise das soluções propostas

A mais simples e direta é a do **@mbigsonbr**, mas fiquei com um pé atrás por causa da criação e inserção de um elemento desnecessariamente.

A resposta do **@Zuul** de clonagem também é simples e interessante, mas também parece ainda mais pesada.

A minha resposta parece muito complexa. Será que é necessário tudo aquilo?

## O teste de desempenho

Decidi então aplicar as diferentes técnicas e fazer um teste de desempenho. Os resultados confirmaram minhas suspeitas:

- A clonagem é muito lenta
- Minha solução foi discretamente mais rápida que as demais quando os elementos estão no mesmo nível, mas devido à complexidade e ao uso excessiva da API do jQuery, quando os estão em níveis diferentes do DOM, o desempenho foi equivalente.

Ainda não satisfeito, cheguei à conclusão de que a solução do **@mgibsonbr** poderia ser facilmente convertida para Javascript puro. Fiz novamente o teste e parece que finalmente achei algo interessante.

Vejamos o resultado no gráfico abaixo:

[image: Desempenho de algoritmos de swap]

A legenda é a seguinte:

- **Azul escuro**: o meu algoritmo com nós do mesmo nível
- **Vermelho**: o meu algoritmo com nós de níveis diferentes
- **Amarelo**: o algoritmo original do **@mgibsonbr** com nós do mesmo nível
- **Verde escuro**: o algoritmo original do **@mgibsonbr** com nós de níveis diferentes
- **Roxo**: o algoritmo modificado do **@mgibsonbr** com nós do mesmo nível
- **Azul claro**: o algoritmo modificado do **@mgibsonbr** com nós de níveis diferentes
- **Pink**: o algoritmo do **@Zuul** com nós do mesmo nível
- **Verde claro**: o algoritmo do **@Zuul** com nós de níveis diferentes

### [Teste no jsperf](http://jsperf.com/swap-dom-elements)

## O meu algoritmo

```js
(function ($) {

    $.fn.swap = function(anotherElement) {

        var sameParentStrategy = function(one, another) {
            var oneIndex = one.index();
            var anotherIndex = another.index();
            var swapFunction = function(first, second, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
                if (firstIndex == secondIndex - 1) {
                    first.insertAfter(second);
                } else {
                    var secondPrevious = second.prev();
                    second.insertAfter(first);
                    first.insertAfter(secondPrevious);
                }
            }
            if (oneIndex < anotherIndex) {
                swapFunction(one, another, oneIndex, anotherIndex);
            } else {
                swapFunction(another, one, anotherIndex, oneIndex);
            }
        };

        var differentParentsStrategy = function(one, another) {
            var positionStrategy = function(e) {
                var previous = e.prev();
                var next = e.next();
                var parent = e.parent();
                if (previous.length > 0) {
                    return function(e) {
                        e.insertAfter(previous);
                    };
                } else if (next.length > 0) {
                    return function(e) {
                        e.insertBefore(next);
                    };
                } else {
                    return function(e) {
                        parent.append(e);
                    };
                }
            }
            var oneStrategy = positionStrategy(one);
            var anotherStrategy = positionStrategy(another);
            oneStrategy(another);
            anotherStrategy(one);
            return this;
        };

        //check better strategy
        var one = $(this);
        var another = $(anotherElement);
        if (one.parent().get(0) == another.parent().get(0)) {
            console.log('sameParentStrategy');
            sameParentStrategy(one, another);
        } else {
            console.log('differentParentsStrategy');
            differentParentsStrategy(one, another);
        }

    };

}(jQuery));
```

### [Demo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxdab/2/).

## O algoritmo modificado do **@mgibsonbr**

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.swap = function(anotherElement) {
        var a = $(this).get(0);
        var b = $(anotherElement).get(0);
        var swap = document.createElement('span');
        a.parentNode.insertBefore(swap, a);
        b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);
        swap.parentNode.insertBefore(b, swap);
        swap.remove();
    }
}(jQuery));
```

## Modo de Usar

```js
$(elementSelector).swap(anotherElementSelector);
```

Comment: Bem, criei essa função de propósito geral que se acopla ao jQuery e troca dois elementos em qualquer tipo de estrutura. Por favor, avaliem e critiquem.

Answer (score 3):

Eis uma função que dá conta de inverter quaisquer elementos que sejam irmãos no DOM, sem utilizar clonagem:

```js
function inverterPosicoes(el1, el2) {
    el1 = $(el1);
    el2 = $(el2);
    var prev = el1.prev();
    var parent = el1.parent();

    // Move o primeiro elemento para a posição do segundo
    el2.after(el1);

    // Move o segundo elemento para onde o primeiro estava
    if (prev.length) {
        // Se o primeiro elemento não era o primeiro filho
        prev.after(el2);
    } else {
        // Se o primeiro elemento era o primeiro filho
        parent.prepend(el2);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/342LP/

Comment: @Guilherme Sua edição me fez pensar... http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/249

Answer (score 2):

Se os elementos forem vizinhos, use `insertBefore`:

```js
$('#div3').insertBefore($('#div2'));
```

### Exemplo

Exemplo executável: http://jsfiddle.net/rodrigorgs/uya47/

### Explicação

A [documentação do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) esclarece:

> Pode-se selecionar um elemento da página e inseri-lo antes de outro:
>
> `$( "h2" ).insertBefore( $( ".container" ) );`
>
> Se um elemento selecionado dessa forma for inserido em um único local no DOM, **ele será movido para o alvo (e não clonado)**.
>
> Se houver mais de um elemento alvo, no entanto, serão inseridas cópias do elemento para cada alvo após o primeiro.

(tradução livre)

Conforme escreveu [@utluiz](/users/227/utluiz), pode-se também usar o [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/); neste caso, inverte-se a ordem dos elementos.

Comment: Não funcionou. Experimente inverter a `#div1` com a `#div4`.

Comment: Você está certo, eu não tinha pensado no caso geral =/

Answer (score 1):

Tente isto:

```js
function alterPosition(idElement1, idElement2){
    var div = $(idElement1).clone();
    $(idElement1).remove();
    $(idElement2).before(div);
}
```

Comment: Preppend não insere **antes** do elemento?

Comment: O correto é o .before(), .prepend() adiciona antes de todo o conteudo da tag selecionada...obrigado pela observação...

Comment: Eu posso estar a ler mal a tua função, mas parece-me que estás a remover o primeiro elemento, e depois vais ao segundo elemento e inseres antes dele o primeiro elemento... ou seja, fica tudo igual, não ocorreu troca de posições! :( ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcpn4/))

Comment: Acho que realmente você entendeu errado, eu excluo o atual, e insiro ele antes do elemento desejado, de acordo com o parametro....

Comment: @KennyRafael Sim, mas no Fiddle com o teu código, as `div` não trocam de posição, ve o link que deixei no comentário. _(posso ter algo errado no Fiddle, se assim for, diz!)_

Comment: Inverta os parâmetros! ;P

Comment: E ai, deu certo?

Comment: Seja pelo menos humilde a ponto de tirar o votedown...

Comment: @KennyRafael Fiz um teste rápido mas não funcionou. Agora em relação ao votoNegativo, lamento mas **não fui eu**... podes aceder ao meu perfil para confirmar que não dei votos negativos a ninguém!

Comment: @KennyRafael Para que garantas que determinado utilizador lê a resposta que colocaste num comentário, utiliza `@nomeDoUtilizador`, para que ele seja notificado que tem uma resposta por ler ;)

Comment: @Zuul Ok então, porém antes de questionar a resposta de outra pessoa, certifique-se de fazer os testes corretamente, pois meu código funciona, pode não ser o ideal, mas funciona e é como eu faria antes de conhecer outras opções, você não precisa falar mal do código dos outros para promover sua resposta.

Comment: @KennyRafael Isto é um pouco estranho, parece que pelo facto de alertar para um detalhe em relação ao teu código passei a ser um "inimigo" ? Só estava a querer ajudar, até me dei ao trabalho de fazer um Fiddle com o teu código para se verificar o que pode estar mal e retificar. Também tive o cuidado de dizer que podia estar a ver mal a questão, mas outras pessoas votaram no comentário o que diz que concordaram com o que foi dito. Honestamente não entendo porque está assim de "pé atrás" em relação a tudo isto.

Comment: Pensares que estou a "promover a minha resposta" através desta tentativa de ajudar, realmente deixa-me um pouco triste! Futuramente vou-me abster de comentar ou alertar para conteúdos das tuas perguntas ou respostas! A critica positiva/negativa não parece cair-te bem! :(